# GetFile processor continually running in Apache NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am using Apache NiFi to copy some local files to HDFS.
I've created a `GetFile` processor bound to a `PutHDFS` processor. The `GetFile` processor recursively queries a **read-only** directory. The problem I'm encountering is that files are being continually copied, for example if I delete the copied files on HDFS, then they re-appear shortly after.

In the `GetFile` processor configuration, I've set `Keep Source File` to **true** because the directory is read-only and it is specified in the [documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.GetFile/) that in read-only directories and if this parameter is set to **false** then the files get ignored :

> If true, the file is not deleted after it has been copied to the
>   Content Repository; this causes the file to be picked up continually
>   and is useful for testing purposes. If not keeping original NiFi will
>   need write permissions on the directory it is pulling from otherwise
>   it will ignore the file.

Is it possible to simply copy each file once ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [ListFile](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ListFile/index.html) and [FetchFile](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.FetchFile/index.html) processors to do this. ListFile will keep track of which files it has seen so far, and will not continue to list them unless they have been modified. Make sure you set Completion Strategy in FetchFile to "None", to ensure no attempt is made to move/delete the file.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Is there a way to reset a processor so that it forgets the already imported files ?

Comment: Yes, stop the ListFile processor, then right-click and choose View State. On the State dialog box there is a link to Clear State.